# How do I pass more than one variable via URL in php?

Tags: php, mysql, url

I am trying to pass multiple variables in a URL in PHP to GET some info, but I don't think it's working.

```
$allowedFunctions = array(
   'returnAllProducts',
   'refreshCurrentProduct'

);


$IDNUM = $_GET[ 'idNum' ];


$functionName = $_GET[ 'func' ];

if( in_array( $functionName, $allowedFunctions ) && function_exists( $functionName ) )
{
    $functionName();
}
```

Then I have the refreshCurrentProduct function:

```
function refreshCurrentProduct() { 
$dbh=mysql_connect ("DATABASE","USER", "PASS") or die('I cannot connect to the database because:'. mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("TABLE");

$query = "SELECT `ID` FROM `PRODUCTS`";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed:'.mysql_error());

$DB_STOCK = mysql_query("SELECT `STOCK` FROM `PRODUCTS`") or die('Query failed:'.mysql_error());

$DB_SHORT = mysql_query("SELECT `MYNAME` FROM `PRODUCTS`") or die('Query failed:'.mysql_error());

$DB_LONG = mysql_query("SELECT `DESCRIPTION` FROM `PRODUCTS`") or die('Query failed:'.mysql_error());

$DB_PRICE = mysql_query("SELECT `PRICE` FROM `PRODUCTS`") or die('Query failed:'.mysql_error());

$DB_SHIP = mysql_query("SELECT `SHIPPING` FROM `PRODUCTS`") or die('Query failed:'.mysql_error());


$ID = mysql_result($result,$IDNUM,"ID");
    $STOCK = mysql_result($DB_STOCK,$IDNUM,"STOCK");
    $SHORT = mysql_result($DB_SHORT,$IDNUM,"MYNAME");
    $LONG = mysql_result($DB_LONG,$IDNUM,"DESCRIPTION");
    $PRICE = mysql_result($DB_PRICE,$IDNUM,"PRICE");        
    $SHIP = mysql_result($DB_SHIP,$IDNUM,"SHIPPING");

    echo '
    //echo $STOCK, $SHORT, etc....

    ';
 }
```

The URL I am using is `products.php?func=refreshCurrentProduct&idNum=4`

In theory, that should display from the row with 4 in it, however, it only displays the info from the first row. If I do a `$IDNUM=5` within the function, it will display the 5th row, so something is wrong with how I pass the information.

Also, how do I create (for instance) $STOCK without having to have so much code in $DB_STOCK? Seems like there has to be a better way...

Comment: `mysql_error` discloses too much information for public error messages (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995351.aspx#securityerrormessages_topic2). Also, the old mysql driver is quite outdated. Look into PDO (http://php.net/PDO) and prepared statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you do (as others already mentioned , `$IDNUM` is not in the scope of the function):

```
function refreshCurrentProduct() { 
    $dbh=mysql_connect ("DATABASE","USER", "PASS") or die('I cannot connect to the database because:'. mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("TABLE");

    // If $_GET['idNum'] is not a number use 0
    $rowNumber = is_numeric($_GET['idNum']) ? $_GET['idNum'] : 0;

    $query = "SELECT ID, STOCK,  MYNAME, DESCRIPTION, PRICE, SHIPPING FROM `PRODUCTS`";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if(mysql_data_seek($result,  $rowNumber)) {
        // The result set has indeed at least $rowNumber rows

        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

        echo $row['ID'];
        echo $row['STOCK'];
        // ... etc ....
    }
    else {
        echo "No such row!";
    }
}
```

No need to hit the database six times! Of course you need to add error handling.

Btw. is the parameter `idNum` the same as the `ID` of the record in the database? If so, you can even further simplify:

```
function refreshCurrentProduct() { 
    $dbh=mysql_connect ("DATABASE","USER", "PASS") or die('I cannot connect to the database because:'. mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("TABLE");

    // If $_GET['idNum'] is not a number use 0
    $id = is_numeric($_GET['idNum']) ? $_GET['idNum'] : 0;

    $query = "SELECT ID, STOCK,  MYNAME, DESCRIPTION, PRICE, SHIPPING FROM `PRODUCTS` WHERE ID = $id";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
       echo "No rows found, nothing to print";
       return;
    }

    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

    echo $row['ID'];
    echo $row['STOCK'];
    // ... etc ....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [call_user_func](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php).

```
$functionName = $_GET[ 'func' ];

if( in_array( $functionName, $allowedFunctions ) && function_exists( $functionName ) )
{
    call_user_func($functionName);
}
```

Also, if I'm reading your code right, you could get all of the info in a single query:

```
$query = "SELECT `ID`,`STOCK`,`MYNAME`,`DESCRIPTION`,`PRICE`,`SHIPPING` FROM `PRODUCTS`";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed:'.mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $ID=$row['ID'];
    //etc.
}
```

Comment: Not quite, the OP wants to get a certain row, not all rows.

Comment: Btw `$functionName()` is not the OPs problem. This works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Your `$IDNUM` variable is outside the scope of your function.  You either need to pass that into your function as a variable or you should be able to set it within the function by setting it inside.

```
function refreshCurrentProduct() { 
  $IDNUM = $_GET[ 'idNum' ];
  ...
}
```